# how to give persistent permissions to a postgres database located in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, permissions, persistence

the problem is the following: I have a docker container with postgres inside a stack that is destroyed and recreated daily, the problem is that every time it is destroyed I have to pass the permissions again, while all the others data persists without problem.

This is part of the compose file that create the postgres container:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    pg_database:
        image: postgres:12
        volumes:
            - /home/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"   
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/etl_pg_usr_v1
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/etl_pg_pass_v1
        secrets:
            - etl_pg_usr_v1
            - etl_pg_pass_v1
```

Comment: Is the volume destroyed as well?

Answer (score 0):

please follow my example for your issue

```
version: '3.1'
services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
          POSTGRES_USER: test
          POSTGRES_DB: buildserver
        volumes:
          - ./buildserver_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```